# AdMob native ad does not show AdChoices icon

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I'm running the example app for native advanced ads from the official repo.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/kotlin/admob/NativeAdvancedExample

When I run it I see ads:

[image]

but as you can see it does not show the adchoices icon in the corner.

I have the same problem in my project.

The rules says that the icon is mandatory and that it will be automatically added, but as we see it is not added and it violates the rules.

Is there a way to force it to be shown?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your xml for custom layout

Comment: It only show when all required things added

Comment: @Hanzala could you list down those required things. I am facing the same issue

Comment: I'm not sure, turned out it appears sometimes, I released the app as it is. 
I think it's a bug in the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but it turns out that the AdChoices icon does not show for test ads: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/issues/136

You need to test it with a real ad unit ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it like this,

```
.withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                .setRequestCustomMuteThisAd(true)
                .setAdChoicesPlacement(ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT)
                .build())
```

Thats it! And also you can position it in four ways Like `ADCHOICES_TOP_LEFT` or `ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT`  or `ADCHOICES_BOTTOM_RIGHT` or `ADCHOICES_BOTTOM_LEFT`

Comment: What object is withNativeAdOptions a function of?

Comment: @JCutting8 withNativeAdOptions is just a setting function in the AdLoader Builder class, which is just used to load a NativeAd, check the native ad guide or documentation on google

Comment: After doing this,do you still need to provide a view for this in the layout?