# AdMob Native Ad Validator Ad Attribution missing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, admob, native-ads

I am trying to integrate Native Ads from AdbMob in iOS with `UIKit`

Below is my code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController,GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate,GADNativeAdDelegate,GADVideoControllerDelegate {
    
    private var adLoader: GADAdLoader!
    
    let adView: GADNativeAdView = {
        let view = GADNativeAdView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
                view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        return view
    }()
    
    let adLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.8, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.text = "Ad"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    let headlineLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        label.text = "Headline Label"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let advertiserLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.text = "Advertiser Label"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let ratingsImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    let bodyLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.text = "This is the body of the card."
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let gadMediaView: GADMediaView = {
        let view = GADMediaView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    let installButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.setTitle("Install", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    let storeLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Store"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    let priceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Price"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        setupConstraints()
        
        let multipleAdOptions = GADMultipleAdsAdLoaderOptions()
        multipleAdOptions.numberOfAds = 5;
        
        adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511",
                               rootViewController: self,
                               adTypes: [.native],
                               options: nil)
        adLoader.delegate = self
        adLoader.load(GADRequest())
        
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        // Constraints for your custom GADUnifiedNativeAdView
        view.addSubview(adView)
        adView.addSubview(adLabel)
        adView.addSubview(iconImageView)
        adView.addSubview(headlineLabel)
        adView.addSubview(advertiserLabel)
        adView.addSubview(ratingsImageView)
        adView.addSubview(bodyLabel)
        adView.addSubview(gadMediaView)
        adView.addSubview(installButton)
        adView.addSubview(storeLabel)
        adView.addSubview(priceLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            adView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            adView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            adView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            adView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            adLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.topAnchor,constant: 4),
            adLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.leadingAnchor,constant: 4),
            adLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30), // Set a specific height for the title label
            adLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            iconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            headlineLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            headlineLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.topAnchor)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            advertiserLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            advertiserLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headlineLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 2),
            
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ratingsImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: advertiserLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            ratingsImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: advertiserLabel.bottomAnchor),
            ratingsImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            ratingsImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 17)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bodyLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            bodyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.leadingAnchor),
            bodyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            gadMediaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            gadMediaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            gadMediaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bodyLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            gadMediaView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            installButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: adView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            installButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gadMediaView.bottomAnchor,constant: 10),
            installButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            installButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            storeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: installButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            storeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: installButton.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            priceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            priceLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: storeLabel.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        nativeAd.delegate = self
        
        iconImageView.image = nativeAd.icon?.image
        
        
        headlineLabel.text = nativeAd.headline
        gadMediaView.mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        let mediaContent = nativeAd.mediaContent
        if mediaContent.hasVideoContent {
            // By acting as the delegate to the GADVideoController, this ViewController receives messages
            // about events in the video lifecycle.
            mediaContent.videoController.delegate = self
            print("Ad contains a video asset.")
        } else {
            print("Ad does not contain a video.")
        }
        bodyLabel.text = nativeAd.body
        advertiserLabel.text = nativeAd.advertiser
        installButton.setTitle(nativeAd.callToAction, for: .normal)
        
        storeLabel.text = nativeAd.store
        priceLabel.text = nativeAd.price
        
        // In order for the SDK to process touch events properly, user interaction should be disabled.
        installButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ratingsImageView.image = imageOfStars(from: nativeAd.starRating)
        
        adView.nativeAd = nativeAd
    }
    
    func imageOfStars(from starRating: NSDecimalNumber?) -> UIImage? {
      guard let rating = starRating?.doubleValue else {
        return nil
      }
      if rating >= 5 {
        return UIImage(named: "stars_5")
      } else if rating >= 4.5 {
        return UIImage(named: "stars_4_5")
      } else if rating >= 4 {
        return UIImage(named: "stars_4")
      } else if rating >= 3.5 {
        return UIImage(named: "stars_3_5")
      } else {
        return nil
      }
    }
    
    func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(adLoader) failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func adLoaderDidFinishLoading(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader) {
        
    }
    
    func nativeAdDidRecordImpression(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad was shown.
    }
    
    func nativeAdDidRecordClick(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad was clicked on.
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillPresentScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad will present a full screen view.
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad will dismiss a full screen view.
    }
    
    func nativeAdDidDismissScreen(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad did dismiss a full screen view.
    }
    
    func nativeAdWillLeaveApplication(_ nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
        // The native ad will cause the app to become inactive and
        // open a new app.
    }
    
    
    func videoControllerDidEndVideoPlayback(_ videoController: GADVideoController) {
        print("Video playback has ended.")
    }
}
```

Below is the output

[image]

I keep getting a validation error saying Ad attribution missing but I have added the a UILabel saying Ad at top left corner but still same validation error

This is the issue it points to

[image]

What else needs to be added

After going through [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6329638) doc, it also says I need to add an image on top right corner, I tried adding a dummy image, I couldn't find the exact image of Ads by Google Icon which is pointed in docs but still same issue

EDIT:

I think I don't need to show icon on top right corner as that s displayed for production ad units automatically by google. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420323/admob-native-ad-does-not-show-adchoices-icon)